# How could I create a custom dozer initializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, dozer

Is it possible to create a custom dozer initializer so it accepts a parameter with the constructor and not just an empty constructor?

For example, next converter failed because of dozer can't initialize it, and throws **java.lang.InstantiationException**

```
public class MyCustomDozerConverter extends DozerConverter<MyObject, String> {

    private static String myParameter;

    // How could dozer accepts this constructor?
    public MyCustomDozerConverter(String myParameter) {
        super(MyObject.class, String.class);
        this.myParameter = myParameter;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertTo(MyObject source, String destination) {      
        // Using value of myParamter which passed in constructor
        // business logic
        return destination;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject convertFrom(String source, MyObject destination) {
        // business logic
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also if it possible, so how can i send this parameter to constructor so it will be dynamic not static?

**Note:** i am using dozer inside spring-boot project

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration class you need to add this section:

```
@Bean
public DozerBeanMapper mapper() throws IOException {
    List<String> mappingFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<CustomConverter> customConverters = new ArrayList<CustomConverter>();
    customConverters.add(new MyCustomDozerConverter(""));

    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    mapper.setMappingFiles(mappingFiles);
    mapper.setCustomConverters(customConverters);

    return mapper;
}
```

In this way dozer will use instance of MyCustomConverter you set in `mapper.setCustomConverters(customConverters)` method.